# 3rd party application and skype

Tags: c#, skype

How can I automatically (programatically) allow 3rd party app to intercati with skype. As i've seen skype manager is the one who pops up the message allow or not the 3rd party app to interract with client. How did IMO IM resolve the problem with skype? Do I need a skype certificate to programtically be able to allow a 3 rd app in skype. THX

Comment: I've never seen IMO before, but it looks like it does not install anything on client machines, so it do not interact with skype (at least not on client machines). What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Have you managed to get your app to interact with skype and want to avoid the "consent" prompt ?

Comment: i want to avoid the allow a 3rd party app to interract to skype message. i would like to programatically allow my app to inerract to skype.

Comment: For me that would defeat the purpose of that message no? I don't think skype provide any way to do that (but I am not sure).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Skype API (and skype needs to be installed as far as I know): http://developer.skype.com/accessories